# Forced Touch with tvOS

Tags: swift, tvos, apple-tv

Does anybody know how to detect a forced touch/click on the remote control with tvOS?

I want to use the click in a Sprite Kit scene to open a 'game paused alert'. I have no UIKit controls which have the focus and will react on the click.

I'm already using the 'normal' touch events on the remote control to move my sprites around.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Apple suggests](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/tvos/documentation/General/Conceptual/AppleTV_PG/DetectingButtonPressesandGestures.html) using `UIPressesEvent`'s to detect presses/clicks.

```
override func pressesBegan(presses: Set<UIPress>, withEvent event: UIPressesEvent?) {
    for item in presses {
        if item.type == .Select {
            self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.greenColor()
        }
    }
}

override func pressesEnded(presses: Set<UIPress>, withEvent event: UIPressesEvent?) {
    for item in presses {
        if item.type == .Select {
            self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
        }
    }
}

override func pressesChanged(presses: Set<UIPress>, withEvent event: UIPressesEvent?) {
    // ignored
}

override func pressesCancelled(presses: Set<UIPress>, withEvent event: UIPressesEvent?) {
    for item in presses {
        if item.type == .Select {
            self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Works perfect. Thanks

Comment: Just a clarification: normally you would implement touch events on uiview (for example) that will receive the touches. However presses are not meant to be specific for a view... so... where do you implement them? In the UIViewController?