# How to detect click-press on the touchpad on Apple TV's remote?

Tags: swift, tvos, siri-remote

How can I detect a "click press", not just a tap, on the touchpad on siri remote?

EDIT:
My main problem was that my view had an UIButton that received the event.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Forced Touch with tvOS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32812468/forced-touch-with-tvos)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

By reading the UIPressesEvent's. [Detecting Gestures and Button Presses](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/tvos/documentation/General/Conceptual/AppleTV_PG/DetectingButtonPressesandGestures.html)

```
override func pressesEnded(presses: Set<UIPress>, withEvent event: UIPressesEvent?) {
    for press in presses {
        if (press.type == .Select) {
           // Select is pressed
        }  else {
            super.pressesEnded(presses, withEvent: event)
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

My main problem was that my view had an UIButton that received the event.
After disabling that button in the storyboard, the pressesBegan / pressesEnded are invoked.